# jQuery get the ID of <li> based on clicked element inside of it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Anyone know how can I get the id of

based on the clicked element inside of it using jQuery?

This is my html tag:

```
<div id="grade_contamina">
    <ul id="ul_element">
        <!---My first li--->
        <li id="first_id">
            <p>
                Apple
            </p>
            <!---Button for apple---->
            <span class="fruits" id="btn_apple">
                <a class="btn_send_once">Send to Students</a>
                <a class="btn_delete_once" >Delete</a>
                <a class="btn_download_once">Download</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <!---My second li--->
        <li id="second_id">
            <p>
                Grapes
            </p>
            <!---Button for grapes---->
            <span class="fruits" id="btn_grapes">
                <a class="btn_send_once">Send to Students</a>
                <a class="btn_delete_once" >Delete</a>
                <a class="btn_download_once">Download</a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Every LI element there is 3 button, the delete, send, and download.
let say from the 'apple LI element', i clicked the delete. i need to delete this LI element base on its id, or i want to send this base on its id. now how can i get the id of LI  or what is the best way to get the ID of LI element?

aside from getting the id, i want to fire a JQUERY effect when the button delete is  clicked.

```
I want this happen if the button delete is clicked.
**Remove the LI element which is  clicked
**Apped a new LI element at the last LI element of ul using "FadeIn Effect".
```

this is my pseudo code

```
if button is clicked{
   var the_id = get the id of LI where the button is clicked
   now which one of button is clicked?
   if button send is  clicked{
     some code here, i will need here the id to send...
   }else if button download is clicked{
     some code here, i will need here the id too..
   }else if button delete is clicked{
     remove the LI element (With fadeOut effect if possible)
     append a new LI element at the end of LI whith fadeIn effect
   }
   //End of Statement
}
```

Anyone can help me? I only have small knowledge in jQuery, so any help will be appreciated. Thank You!!!

Comment: hi, what do you mean by li base?

Comment: this.id should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="grade_contamina">
    <ul id="ul_element">
        <!---My first li--->
        <li id="first_id">
            <p>
                Apple
            </p>
            <!---Button for apple---->
            <span class="fruits" id="btn_apple">
                <a class="btn_send_once">Send to Students</a>
                <a class="btn_delete_once" >Delete</a>
                <a class="btn_download_once">Download</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <!---My second li--->
        <li id="second_id">
            <p>
                Grapes
            </p>
            <!---Button for grapes---->
            <span class="fruits" id="btn_grapes">
                <a class="btn_send_once">Send to Students</a>
                <a class="btn_delete_once" >Delete</a>
                <a class="btn_download_once">Download</a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#grade_contamina').on('click', 'a', function() {
        var btn_name = $(this).attr('class')
        var id = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
        if(btn_name == 'btn_send_once'){
            alert(btn_name+" within "+id);
            //your code
        }else if(btn_name == 'btn_delete_once'){
            alert(btn_name+" within "+id);
        }else{
            alert(btn_name+" within "+id);
        }
    })
})
```

The above code will get you the `button`'s `class` along with its `li`'s `id`

Answer (score 4):

To get the `id` of `li` on the `a` click, you need to use `closest`.
This will get the closest `li` ancestor of the clicked element.

```
$('#grade_contamina').on('click', 'a', function() {
    alert($(this).closest('li').attr('id'));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuerys .attr(propertyname) like I did in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/d907e6gm/

```
$('ul > li').click(function(){
alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: If you want to attach the eventhandler to your anchor element, you could also use parent() or in your case two parents if the structure is always the same. alert($(this).parent().parent().attr('id'));

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to give all the code. I will just show you, how to get list item id and which button you have clicked.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ul_element a").on("click",function(){
    idli = $(this).closest("li").attr("id"); // your list item id.
    val = $(this).text(); // your link text       
   });
 });
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/4uaw5ws7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering `.parents()` of clicked `a` , returning `id` of `a` parent `li`

```js
$("#grade_contamina a").on("click", function() {
  console.log($(this).parents("li")[0].id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grade_contamina">
    <ul id="ul_element">
        <!---My first li--->
        <li id="first_id">
            <p>
                Apple
            </p>
            <!---Button for apple---->
            <span class="fruits" id="btn_apple">
                <a class="btn_send_once">Send to Students</a>
                <a class="btn_delete_once" >Delete</a>
                <a class="btn_download_once">Download</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <!---My second li--->
        <li id="second_id">
            <p>
                Grapes
            </p>
            <!---Button for grapes---->
            <span class="fruits" id="btn_grapes">
                <a class="btn_send_once">Send to Students</a>
                <a class="btn_delete_once" >Delete</a>
                <a class="btn_download_once">Download</a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```